# Load data Query hive using file path in windows

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load data in hive through a java program. I am loading the file from my machine.

```
stmt.executeQuery("load data local inpath  'file:///C:/sample/Documents/sample1.txt'  into table " + tablename);
```

When I execute this program I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException:Expected scheme-specific part at index 2: C:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2835)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3038)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:753)
```

However when I execute the program in a ubuntu machine

```
stmt.executeQuery("load data local inpath  '/home/sample/sample1.txt'  into table " + tablename);
```

The data is loaded correctly to the hive database.

When I execute the program in windows I am getting the exception. How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess you need to send the data first from local to Hadoop. For doing so search for Java API equi of `hadoop fs -put` and once data is in Hadoop you can do load data easily.

Comment: @abhiieor ya from HDFS I can access the file.My doubt is when i execute the program in Ubuntu machine it's working when I try in  windows by changing file path alone  it's showing the above mentioned exception.

Answer (score 0):

Path(Uri) syntax in windows is different from ubuntu. In ubuntu we use forward slash where as in windows we use backslash.

Windows: C:\Users\system\Desktop\db

Linux: /home/sample/sample1.txt'

So try changing the syntax of the uri.

Comment: I am getting the following exception when I changed the Path.           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException:Relative path in absolute URI

Comment: I think you are using local keyword and file://.  try this:  load data local inpath 'C:\sample\Documents\sample1.txt'. no need to mention file system when you are using local keyword.

Comment: when i give path like this 'C:\sample\Documents\sample1.txt' i am getting error like invalid escape sequence so tried like this 'C:\\sample\\Documents\\sample1.txt' still i am getting same exception and also i removed file:// from the path.

Comment: I think it should work.Try using double quotes for the path.